# Showing a DataTable. I can make a table with a dynamical number of rows, but how to make a dynamical number of columns inside the rows?

Tags: c#, maui

My program needs to open a file, make operations, and show the table on the screen. This means that the number of lines and columns depends on the file.

myFunc.generateDataTable() returns the DataTable that I want to exhibit. In WPF, I would simply bind this to a DataGrid.

For now, I can make a table that has a dynamical number of lines using an IEnumerablelist of Rows, but I don't know how to make a dynamical number of columns for each element inside the row.

The code showing the table with dynamical lines but not columns:

C# code snippet:

```
        EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> table = myFunc.generateDataTable().AsEnumerable();
        GenerateTable.ItemsSource = table;
```

The full XAML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>


<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyClass.TablePage"
             Title="GeneratingTable">
    

    <CollectionView Grid.Row="1"  x:Name="GenerateTable" VerticalOptions="Start" ItemsLayout="VerticalList" Margin ="5,5,5,5" Background = "WhiteSmoke">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="10" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke">

                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding [1]}" />
                    
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>

</ContentPage>
```

The label inside is showing the item in the index [1] of each row. Ideally I would just need to replace the Label with something else that could print every index of the row. Or I could dynamically create labels, but I don't know how.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: a CollectionView really isn't designed for tabular data.  If you have a couple of columns you could make it work, but for a large number it's probably not a good idea.  There are third party datagrids you could look at - XF had several, but I'm not sure what the status is on MAUI.  Which platforms do you need to support?

Comment: @Jason it should be compatible with at least Windows and Mac, but it would be nice if it worked elsewhere too.

Do you have alternatives for CollectionView? I am going to print a few columns and a lot of lines (in the thousands).

Answer (score 0):

In general,if we want to disply a list of row data,we need to create an Item model(That's what you call `DataRow`) and create the fields we need(That's what you call `column1`,`column2` and so on) in the item model.

For example:

```
 public class DataRow
{
    public string column1 { get; set; }

    public string column2 { get; set; }

    public string column3 { get; set; }
}
```

And you can define the row layout in the `DataTemplate` of `CollectionView` and bind above columns of `DataRow`, for example:

```
     <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <Grid Padding="10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Column="0" 
                           Source="{Binding column1 }" 
                           Aspect="AspectFill"
                           HeightRequest="60" 
                           WidthRequest="60" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" 
                           Text="{Binding column2 }" 
                           FontAttributes="Bold" 
                           VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="2"  
                           Text="{Binding column3 }"
                           FontAttributes="Italic" 
                           VerticalOptions="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: This is useful, thanks. I need the number of columns to be dynamical, so I can't declare them manually like you did here.

Comment: You didn't know the number of columns beforehand? So how did you get the data? Does your row of data (including all columns) not belong to an object?

Comment: It creates a DataTable object with a dynamical number of rows and columns. There are a couple of for loops to do that, and the function returns the DataTable that I want to print. That part is solved. All I need is to get the DataTable and put it on the screen.

Comment: In general, we need to know the names of these columns (That's what you call DataRow) so that we can use data binding to display them to the corresponding Labels.

Comment: You can make your own DataGrid control.And you could put a horizontal CollectionView in the DataTemplate for the main collection view or use [BindableLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts).